# Find out Python version from source code (or Heroku)

Tags: python, django, heroku, version

We run a site called inteokej.nu and I need to find out which version of Python it runs on. I have pulled all the files to my computer but I don't know if and how I can find out the version number from them? The site is hosted on Heroku and maybe there's a way to find out the version with some kind of Heroku command?

As for now I don't have any possibilities to change any code (e.g. add a code snippet to get the version).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you don't want to get the version number programmatically? You want to get the version number under which the source was created by analyzing the source code, but not adding any code to it?

Comment: @Neftas: If possible, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you need. Either (a) the version you are running on or (b) the version under the .pyc file was compiled?

**a.** If you need to know the python **version you are running**, do the following:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> print sys.version_info.major
2
>>> print sys.version_info.minor
7
>>> print sys.version_info.micro
3
>>> print '%s.%s.%s' % (sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor, sys.version_info.micro)
2.7.3
```

**b.** If you want to know the python **version under a .pyc file was compiled**, do the following:

```
>>> f = open('somefile.pyc')
>>> magic = f.read(4)
>>> magic
'\x03\xf3\r\n'
>>> magic.encode('hex')
'03f30d0a'
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack("<HH", magic)
(62211, 2573)
>>> struct.unpack("<HH", magic)[0]
62211
```

The known values are listed in the python source file `Python/import.c`. Here the known values from Python 2.7.10rc1:

```
   Python 1.5:   20121
   Python 1.5.1: 20121
   Python 1.5.2: 20121
   Python 1.6:   50428
   Python 2.0:   50823
   Python 2.0.1: 50823
   Python 2.1:   60202
   Python 2.1.1: 60202
   Python 2.1.2: 60202
   Python 2.2:   60717
   Python 2.3a0: 62011
   Python 2.3a0: 62021
   Python 2.3a0: 62011 (!)
   Python 2.4a0: 62041
   Python 2.4a3: 62051
   Python 2.4b1: 62061
   Python 2.5a0: 62071
   Python 2.5a0: 62081 (ast-branch)
   Python 2.5a0: 62091 (with)
   Python 2.5a0: 62092 (changed WITH_CLEANUP opcode)
   Python 2.5b3: 62101 (fix wrong code: for x, in ...)
   Python 2.5b3: 62111 (fix wrong code: x += yield)
   Python 2.5c1: 62121 (fix wrong lnotab with for loops and
                        storing constants that should have been removed)
   Python 2.5c2: 62131 (fix wrong code: for x, in ... in listcomp/genexp)
   Python 2.6a0: 62151 (peephole optimizations and STORE_MAP opcode)
   Python 2.6a1: 62161 (WITH_CLEANUP optimization)
   Python 2.7a0: 62171 (optimize list comprehensions/change LIST_APPEND)
   Python 2.7a0: 62181 (optimize conditional branches:
            introduce POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE and POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE)
   Python 2.7a0  62191 (introduce SETUP_WITH)
   Python 2.7a0  62201 (introduce BUILD_SET)
   Python 2.7a0  62211 (introduce MAP_ADD and SET_ADD)
```

To solve your problem, you could recursively walk your directory and extract the values from every .pyc file and populate a dictionary with a list of files for every value/version. See following example:

```py
import os, struct

your_path = '/your/path' # <- enter your path here
values = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(your_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pyc'):
            full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            value = struct.unpack("<HH", open(full_path).read(4))[0] # <- evtl. enclose this in a try block
            if not values.has_key(value):
                values[value] = []
            values[value].append(full_path)
            print '%s %s' % (value, full_path)

for value, files in values.items():
    print 'Following files have value %s' % (value)
    for file in files:
        print '    %s' % (file)
```

If you are under Linux, you could solve your problem with the following one line commando (thanks to Neftas suggestion!):

```
dir=/your/path; find ${dir} -name "*.pyc" | while read file; do head -c 2 ${file} | od -d | head -n 1 | awk -v z=${file} -F ' ' '{print $2 "\t" z}'; done
```

This outputs a list with value and filename like the following:

```
62211   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/reportbug/ui/urwid_ui.pyc
62211   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/reportbug/debbugs.pyc
62211   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/reportbug/checkbuildd.pyc
...
62161   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/debianbts.pyc
62161   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/fpconst.pyc
62161   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/SOAPpy/Server.pyc
...
```

Comment: Awesome! But do how do you get from `d1f20d0a` to any of the values in your `import.c`?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I couldn't find `import.c` for my Python 2.7 installation, but for Python 3, I found that the data you mention was in `importlib/_bootstrap.py`. You can also check this info in Unix with just the standard tools, using `head -1 file.pyc | od -xcd`.

Comment: @Neftas: thanks for the Unix hint. I've added a "ready to use" command line in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the least complex answer (for Heroku) is missing:

Log into Heroku bash session, something like this in your authenticated terminal:

```
heroku run bash --app YOURAPPNAME
```

then type:

```
python --version
```

## done

Answer (score 1):

You want to know what runtime is used to run your code on Heroku. At the time of writing this, new applications default to the `Python 2.7.9` runtime. This may have been modified in the 'runtime.txt' file so to find out if it has been set:

```
$ cat runtime.txt
python-3.4.2
```

Comment: cat runtime.txt outputs "cat: runtime.txt: No such file or directory" ?

Comment: As the file does not exist it means your applications on Heroku are run by default on the Python 2.7.9 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't have access to source code, from headers I can see that server is using Gunicorn 0.17.2, which is compatible with Python 2.x >= 2.6, which rules out i.e. Python 3.