# Is it possible to check if python sourcecode was written only for one version (python 2 or python 3)

Tags: python

I make some source code analysis and need to know if the source code was written only for one version (python 2 or python 3). Ideally without starting the script with both runtimes and check if it raises an exception. I dont want to check which runtimes are installed like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320265/find-out-python-version-from-source-code-or-heroku).

Maybe I am looking for some sort of linter, which tests for typical python 2 code like

> print "hello"

instead of

> print("hello")

This is my problem I read a file like this for example:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(True) if (i % 2 == 1) else print(False)
```

which works fine under python 3 and raises an error for python2

```
print(True) if (i % 2 == 1) else print(False)
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Maybe with the [compiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html#module-compiler) but it is marked as deprecated

Any thoughts for solving this problem or any known linter which tells me if the code is python 2 or 3 ? Or is running the file with both runtimes my only option?

Thanks

Comment: Some code is written to work on *both*. If there is a `from __future__ import print_function` at the top, `print()` will work on both versions.

Comment: Does `from __future__ import print_function` work on Python 3 itself?

Comment: @lilezek: it will, that's the whole point of the technique.

Comment: okay i will change the title only for one version

Comment: @fuubah: that still won't make a difference. Because such code exists you cannot be certain that code is written for one or the other version.

Comment: i mean i can, if the code contains print "hello" it does not work on python3 ?! and like my print example it does not work on python2, so maybe there are some lists of indicators, which indicate this is python2 or this is python3 ?

Comment: @fuubah what are you actually trying to achieve? There are syntactic changes across Python versions that you could look for, like `print` becoming a function and `except ErrorType, err:` being removed, and e.g. the `@` operator and `*` argument being added but there's also a lot of polyglot (2.x-3.x-compatible) code out there.

Comment: @fuubah,  there are a limited amount of things that would make code specific to 2 or 3, if your code  did not contain them then it is ambiguous

Comment: @jonrsharpe i want to do some source code analysis and try to analyse different python projects but I stumbled over my print example and came up with this question, but I think Martijn Pieters answered my Question

Comment: If you had .pyc files you actually could check the version it was compiled with using the magic number

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks for the idea

Comment: No worries, you just need to `magic_num = f.read(4).encode("hex")` then compare it to a dict of magic numbers mapped to versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reliably detect that code was written for Python 3 only.

If code uses `print` as a *statement* you can be certain it will only work on Python 2. Similarly, code using `except Exception, target:` is only going to run on Python 2.

But it is possible to write *polyglot* Python code; code that'll run on both Python 2 and 3, by using [`from __future__` statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future); `from __future__ import print_function` will let you use the `print()` function on Python 2, for example.

Your best bet is to go through the [major Python 3 syntax changes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#common-stumbling-blocks), and create a series of *heuristics* to make an educated guess about the Python version.

The Python-Future project has a [helpful cheatsheet](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html) that probably is of help here too.