# How to determine if a library (for example on pypi.org) is good for Python 3

Tags: python

This is a generic question, but for example, I found [pyxser](https://pypi.org/project/pyxser/#:%7E:text=pyxser%20stands%20for%20Python%20XML,tree%20and%20the%20XML%20tree.) and I want to know if it's going to work with Python 3 or not.  I wasted 15-20 minutes earlier today finding out the '[Gnosis](https://pypi.org/project/Gnosis/)' was not.

I see the date on this particular package is March 2011, so I'm guessing it's not.

Is everything on pypi.org ancient?  Is there a better site to use?

Basically, we all do a Google search for something like "xml serializer for Python" and we get a mix of Python 2 and 3 libraries.

Here is a similar question with no answer: [Determining for which python version a library is designed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880071/determining-for-which-python-version-a-library-is-designed)

But the point is we need have a technique to find out for any library what releases it is compatible with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is everything on pypi.org ancient?

No.

> Is there a better site to use?

No.

> But the point is we need have a technique to find out for any library what releases it is compatible with.

There’s no such technique for *any* library, but many libraries will have:

- language [classifiers](https://pypi.org/classifiers/) on PyPI – specifically, the ones that start with “Programming Language :: Python ::” are helpful here, with “Programming Language :: Python :: 3” indicating Python 3 support and “Programming Language :: Python :: 2 :: Only” indicating a lack of it. (See the sidebar of https://pypi.org/project/lxml/ for an example.)
- [`python_requires`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48777286/707111), which PyPI also displays
- wheels with an indication of Python versions in the “Download files” page. `cp3x` is a wheel for CPython 3.x, again indicating Python 3 support. (Example for this at https://pypi.org/project/lxml/#files.)

Comment: Thanks, same comment to other answer: Hmmm.  Gnosis doesn't have any of those, but link to pyxser I included has a lot - including versions of Python under "Programming Languages" under "Classifiers".  I guess it's up to each author to correctly classify his or her own code library.  Guessing the old ones like Gnosis don't, or that feature wasn't available back then.

Answer (score 1):

pypi.org has a small section on the left called `requirements`. Check that and It should show which version of python you need.

When your searching for a package you can also filter by ones that will only run on Python 3.

Comment: Hmmm.  Gnosis doesn't have any of those, but link to pyxser I included has a lot - including versions of Python under "Programming Languages" under "Classifiers".  I guess it's up to each author to correctly classify his or her own code library.  Guessing the old ones like Gnosis don't, or that feature wasn't available back then.

Comment: Yeah. Just like with any software the documentation is up to the vendors. there is not system in place to enforce versioning (maybe they should be...)

Comment: Do you have one that shows "Requirements", I checked a few.  Or did you mean classifiers/languages?

Comment: I think I saw it in Flask.. I just realized It must be something that's added manually. So again, It's not enforced. Although when using libraries made for python 2 there should be dead give-aways like the `print` function. Most newer libraries should support some version of python 3.