# How to tell if a python module is intended to be python 2 or python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 2 and Python 3 have subtle differences which mean that it is not possible to look at a python module and certainly know, just from automatic code analysis, if it will work identically on python 2 and python 3. (Right? That seems to be the answer to [Is it possible to check if python sourcecode was written only for one version (python 2 or python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957645/is-it-possible-to-check-if-python-sourcecode-was-written-only-for-one-version-p) )

Therefore, I suppose there *must* be some convention by which a developer can annotate a file to explicitly indicate that it is intended to be compatible with Python 2, Python 3, or both, so that this annotation can be read by developers, checked automatically, etc..

What is this convention?

I don’t see different file extensions, like .py2 vs .py3.  I don’t see any global variable declaration intended to act as metadata. But it seems like something *must* exist, beyond ad hoc comments in code and readme files. So what is it?

Comment: Generally if it is a widely distributed package, the PIP or Conda metadata will indicated what versions of Python is can be used on.  If it is a privately built module, then I would look first at any `print` commands.  If it is a print statement: `print x`, it is only for python 2.

Comment: Why *must* there be something like this?

Comment: Why must there be a way? Beyond addhoc comments and little things like print(x) vs print x there really isn't.

Comment: (Depressing subjective empirical observations): If you are lucky, it's modelled as requirement in setup.py / package-resources. If not, *readme's* have been the most important source for me with the following result: if it's py3 only, people usually warn about that! If it's py2 only, this is often unmentioned (as this was not important in the past; so yes, more for old unmaintained projects). (the keyword *depressing* somewhat tackles the *why* in previous comments; it's not an issue with well-maintained software, but with smaller ones)

Comment: The convention is documentation.

Comment: Imagine you had two different programming languages installed on your system, like python and ruby. But unfortunately _these_ two languages are so superficially similar that only a careful analysis can tell them apart, and in fact each language’s interpreter will happily try to run the other language’s source code with subtle, unpredictable results. In that situation, I’d just assume everyone would use file extensions, shebangs, or in-file annotation to prevent mixups — because it would be insane not to! That’s why I assumed there “must” be some way to do it with python 2 vs python 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not really any official way to specify it.  However, a common way that's widely used is to specify the required Python version in the distribution's metadata.

You may see a line in the `setup.py` file (or the `setup.cfg` file, for modern versions of setuptools) declaring the [`python_requires` option](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=python_requires#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) using the [PEP440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) syntax.  See also [PEP 345 - Metadata for Python Software Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/), specifically the section about [environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/#environment-markers) and [Requires-Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/#requires-python) metadata.  Using these markers will prevent pip from downloading/installing a distributions with an incorrect Python interpreter version.

For older packages, it's usually just mentioned in the docs or README file, or using [trove classifiers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers).  This is often listed on the PyPI and/or github landing page.